# Oracle ADF: 12c Unresponsive Script (core-ABRAMS-3160.js)

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.

Script: domain:7101/portal/afr/partition/gecko/n/default/opt/d/table-ABRAMS-3160.js:208

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<f:view xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">  
    <af:document title="serviceRequest.jsf" id="d1">  
        <af:form id="f1">  
            <af:pageTemplate viewId="/templates/FsvTemplate.jsf" id="pt1">  
                <f:facet name="Content">  
                    <af:panelGridLayout id="pgl1">  
                        <af:gridRow marginTop="5px" height="auto" id="gr1">  
                            <af:gridCell marginStart="5px" width="auto" id="gc1">  
                                <af:panelTabbed id="pt2">  
                                    <af:showDetailItem text="Service Request Search" id="sdi1">  
                                        <af:outputText value="service request search" id="ot2"/>  
                                    </af:showDetailItem>  
                                    <af:showDetailItem text="Service Request Header" id="sdi2" disclosed="true">  
                                        <af:outputText value="Search" id="ot1"/>  
                                    </af:showDetailItem>  
                                    <af:showDetailItem text="Lines and Tasks" id="sdi3" disabled="true"/>  
                                    <af:showDetailItem text="Assignment and Scheduling" id="sdi4" disabled="true"/>                                      
                                </af:panelTabbed>  
                            </af:gridCell>  
                        </af:gridRow>  
                    </af:panelGridLayout>     
                </f:facet>  
            </af:pageTemplate>  
        </af:form>  
    </af:document>  
</f:view>
```

How can i deal with this issue?
Thanks

Comment: How about some context? Did you try Google for "A script on this page may be busy"?  Please start there.

Comment: Leute this error occurs in special contexte. If u couldn't help me?, at least avoid voting down

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect... You have not provided ANY details at all on your code.  Nobody knows what `table-ABRAMS-3160.js` is, and nobody can possibly help you unless you provide a lot more details.

Comment: the context was expressiv: Oracle-Adf

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3527282?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the answer. Thanks to **Kyle.Thomas** who posts his answer on https://community.oracle.com/thread/3527282?start=0&tstart=0

It only appears to be an issue when I have the:

```
<af:panelTabbed id="pt1">
```

within

```
<af:panelGridLayout id="pgl1">
               <af:gridRow marginTop="5px" height="auto" id="gr1"> 
                    <af:gridCell marginStart="5px" width="auto" id="gc1">
```